# (ringinuse disabled) (Invalid) has taken no calls yet

Tags: linux, asterisk, sip, pbx, freepbx

I had a freepbx server in place. I setup a queue with static agents and ring all strategy. Now, suddenly no body in the queue will ring once the call routed to the queue. 
I check the queue and found out that all the phones are on this status "(ringinuse disabled) (Invalid) has taken no calls yet". Before it work smoothly until few weeks ago  this thing happen.

- Asterisk 11.23.0
- FreePBX 12.0.76.4
- Not running FreePBX distro
- ubuntu-14

Answer (score 0):

From the [sample configuration file](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/53ed437db3f37d941538ec1bf0ff96c422c7bef5/configs/samples/queues.conf.sample#L462):

> **Invalid:** Do not consider a member to be available if he has an "invalid" device
>   state. This generally is caused by an error condition in the member's
>   channel driver.

Check with the channel driver if the device is reporting a valid state. For example, you can check `sip show peer FOO` for chan_sip.